# Mystery Border Around HTML Table Row

Tags: html, css, html-table, format

I have a fairly simple table with two rows, each of which has one cell.  The table has a colored border.  The top row/cell has a white background.  The bottom row/cell has a colored background.  The problem is that the bottom row/cell has a thin, white border that I do not want there.  Can anyone suggest a code modification to get rid of that border?  My code is below, and [here is a screenshot](https://paste.pics/1be08f5fbf533739ffa7c2edee5bbb0b) with the purple arrows pointing to the border that I am trying to eliminate.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table1 {
            border: 4px solid #FF7C7C;
            float: initial;
        }
        .td1 {
            width: 530px;
            padding: 5px 35px 5px 35px;
            font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif; 
            font-size: 16px; 
            line-height: 22px;
            color: #62605d;
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table1">
        <tr class="td1">
            <td class="td1" style="text-align: center;">
                Text line 1.<br />
                Text line 2.<br />
                Text line 3.
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-style: none;">
            <td class="td1" style="border: none; border-spacing: 0px; background-color: #FF7C7C; color: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">
                Text line 1.<br />
                Text line 2.<br />
                Text line 3.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Thank you to @Alohci, @lv_ and @PleaseDontHurtMe.jpeg for those quick responses.  Interestingly, the border-spacing tag for table fixed the problem when previewed on w3schools, but when I made the change in Visual Studio the border remained.  I had to add the border-collapse tag to fix it for Visual Studio.  Ah, the mysteries of HTML...

Comment: You were close. `border-spacing: 0` goes on the table, not the td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `border-collapse: collapse;` in your `.table1`

Answer (score 0):

Table has default border-spacing

```
.table1 {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```